# How can I get the "click" function in this code to repeat?

Tags: javascript

This code executes the "Click" function, but only one time. I would like it to repeated the click function until the timeout occurs.

I wanted to try setInterval instead of setTimeout, but was afraid I would create a race condition.

````
var M = 12;     // january=1
var d = 29;     // 1st=1
var h = 11;     // 24h time
var m = 12;
var s = 0;

// How long after the target to stop clicking, in milliseconds.
var duration = 100000;

// How long prior to the start time to click, in milliseconds, to
// account for network latency.
var networkLatency = 150;

// HTML ID of the button to click.
var element = "btnbookdates";

// =====================================
// End configuration section
// =====================================

function getMillisecondsLeft() {
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var targetDate = new Date(y,M-1,d,h,m,s); 
    return targetDate - nowDate;
}
function click() {
    var button = document.getElementById('btnbookdates');
    if ( button ) {
        window.console.log('clicked at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
        button.click();
    } else {
        window.console.log('nothing to click at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
    }
}
if (getMillisecondsLeft() > 0) {
    window.console.log('queueing at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
    setTimeout(click, getMillisecondsLeft() - networkLatency);
} else if (-getMillisecondsLeft() <= duration) {
    click();
} else {
    window.console.log('all done at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
}```
````

Comment: What would be wrong with using setInterval? That's the exact purpose of that method unless the intervals aren't regular.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the click to stop when everything is done, i.e the else part at the end. You could try something like this:

```
var M = 12;     // january=1
var d = 29;     // 1st=1
var h = 11;     // 24h time
var m = 12;
var s = 0;

// How long after the target to stop clicking, in milliseconds.
var duration = 100000;

// How long prior to the start time to click, in milliseconds, to
// account for network latency.
var networkLatency = 150;

// HTML ID of the button to click.
var element = "btnbookdates";

// =====================================
// End configuration section
// =====================================

function getMillisecondsLeft() {
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var targetDate = new Date(y,M-1,d,h,m,s); 
    return targetDate - nowDate;
}
function click() {
    var button = document.getElementById('btnbookdates');
    if ( button ) {
        window.console.log('clicked at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
        button.click();
    } else {
        window.console.log('nothing to click at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
    }
}

var timer ={};
if (getMillisecondsLeft() > 0) {
    window.console.log('queueing at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
    timer = setInterval(click, getMillisecondsLeft() - networkLatency);
} else if (-getMillisecondsLeft() <= duration) {
    click();
} else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    window.console.log('all done at '+getMillisecondsLeft());
}
```